# IBM MQ provider for JMS : How to automatically roll back messages?

Tags: ibm-mq, spring-jms

Working versions in the app

- IBM AllClient version           : 'com.ibm.mq:com.ibm.mq.allclient:9.1.1.0'
- org.springframework:spring-jms  :  4.3.9.RELEASE
- javax.jms:javax.jms-api         :  2.0.1

My requirement is that in case of the failure of a message processing due to say, consumer not being available (eg. DB is unavailable), the message remains in the queue or put back on the queue (if that is even possible). This is because the order of the messages is important, messages have to be consumed in the same order that they are received. The Java app is single-threaded.

I have tried the following

```java
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message)
{
   try{
      if(message instanceOf Textmessage)
      {
      }
   
      :

      : 
      throw new Exception("Test");// Just to test the retry
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
            try
            {
                int temp = message.getIntProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount");
                throw new RuntimeException("Redlivery attempted ");
                // At this point, I am expecting JMS to put the message back into the queue.
                // But it is actually put into the Bakout queue.
            }
            catch(JMSException ef)
            {
                String temp = ef.getMessage();
            }

    }
}
```

I have set this in my spring.xml for the jmsContainer bean.

```xml
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
```

What is wrong with the code above ?

And if putting the message back in the queue is not practical, how can one browse the message, process it and, if successful, pull the message (so it is consumed and no longer on the queue) ? Is this scenario supported in IBM provider for JMS?

The IBM MQ Local queue has `BOTHRESH(1)`.

Comment: This is not a local queue. The Queue Manager and the queues are on a separate server. In any case, poison messages are rare in our system. What is of more concern is dropped messages because they could not be inserted into the DB/or consumed. In other words, transaction support. But I am new to the IBM MQ classes for JAVA (and ours is a Spring application so all object instantiation is done by Spring) and am not sure if rollback() will actually put messages back on the queue.

Comment: Assuming I get those values from my admin , how can I use those values. And how do I do a session rollback() on an exception?. The session object itself is inaccessible in the onMessage() method.  While debugging, I am seeing that the moment the message appears on the queue, the onMessage() is triggered and the message disappears from the queue

Comment: Thank you and sure, please go ahead with writing as an answer. I just checked the queue attributes (read-only for us, of course) and the Backout Threshold is set to 1. So, when an exception is thrown,  the backout count of the message is incremented by 1. But  if I reduce the BOTHRESH to 0 for that queue, then on the first retry, the the condition "backout count" >= 0 will be satisfied for the message and message will move to the backout queue wouldn't it ? Sorry, I am missing something obvious .....

Comment: Increasing the BOTHRESH and adding <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" /> made the retry possible. Please put your suggestions into a reply, and I will mark it as such.

Comment: What did you increase it to?   It would still end up in the `BOQNAME` if you retry `BOTHRESH` times.   You said order matters,  wouldn't setting it to `BOTHRESH(0)` to disable poison message handling meet your requirement better?

Comment: The original question suggested that no rollback was observed. The rollback would be triggered by an Exception being thrown in the `Message Listener`. I tested with `setSessionTransacted(true)` on my `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` and by adding `throws Exception` on my listener declaration. In the listener code, you can inspect `JMSXDeliveryCount` to blackout pragmatically or using `BOTHRESH` on the queue as [@Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7264620/joshmc) says.

Comment: @JoshMc - I have increased it to 4. After your explanation of poison messages, I saw messages with invalid values in our BAKOUT queues. If we rollback continuously, these would cause retries forever and could cause system backups having messages dropped by the Producer end ! So, we are making a trade-off with putting messages into the BAKOUT queue after the BOTHRESH number. We will be working on maybe consuming the BAKOUT queue after recovering from catastrophic JPA errors.

Comment: Ok.  Got it.  You might also want to add a delay before you call roll back otherwise the 4 backouts could happen quickly back to back.  I will write it up and provide links to the IBM docs on the subject as well, as they can be hard to find.

Comment: @JoshMC - Exactly the problem I was thinking about ! :) Everywhere that I have read, IBM MQ does not support a REdelivery delay (it supports a DELIVERY delay which is not what I want). Ideally I'd want this to be "sliding window" delivery times (attempt 1 -delay of 20 sec, attempt 2 - delay of 30 secs etc. but I'll settle for a constant delay) Otherwise, since I have a JMS app with the asynchronous onMessage() call, I am looking for a suitable pattern to implement because I obviously don't want to block. Would appreciate the writeup as it will help others as much as it has helped me, thanks !

Comment: I think you would be stuck with implementing a delay yourself, as @richc mentioned you can inquire the backout count of the message via the `JMSXDeliveryCount` property.  If you understand the cause of your error then you could possibly set the sliding delay based on the deliver count and the cause of the error.

Comment: @user1554876 re. delayed rollback, if you're working JMS2.0 you could use delivery delay in your error handling to put the message back to the input queue under a transaction and the QM will delay the delivery. The application could delay the rollback, or alternatively you might be able to use another queue as a temporary 'blackout q', monitor this and re-queue messages to the input queue after a certain wait period. Is your original problem with rollback resolved?

Comment: @richc according to the OP question "My requirement is that in case of the failure of a message processing due to say, consumer not being available (eg. DB is unavailable), the message remains in the queue or put back on the queue (if that is even possible). This is because the order of the messages is important, messages have to be consumed in the same order that they are received." , delayed delivery would not preserve this order.

Comment: You say "The Java app is single-threaded.", but for a async message listener to work it has to be multithreaded, the message listener will be on it's own thread.  If you mean the you are only allowing one instance of onMessage to be called at a time AND you saw that "order of the messages is important", then why would it matter if you did a thread.sleep in your onmessage prior to the rollback?

Comment: Your sleep strategy could be multiplied by `JMSXDeliveryCount` to escalate the delay e.g., 0x5000, 1x5000, 2x5000 ... However, if the processing problem is related to the message itself, at some point you'll have to back it out. If you need to stop further processing until the problem is resolved, it might be possible to stop the listener. Depending on your scenario, stopping the listener could likely lead to a full queue. Apologies for the confusion @JoshMc

Comment: @richc, the OP did say that after 4 it's ok to send to the BOQNAME.  This is why I suggested adding a delay before the call to rollback.

Comment: @JoshMc - When I say, it is single-threaded, I mean that JMS's asynchronous onMessage() listener is on a single thread. My understanding is that one CAN have multiple threads doing async processing (See - https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html#setMaxConcurrentConsumers(int)) . In our app, the "maxConcurrentConsumers" value is set to 1 and since the Default "consurrentConsumers" is 1 , the onMessage() listener is on a single thread.

Comment: If I understand it correctly then sleeping in the onMessage thread would only impact that listener with maxConcurrentConsumers set to 1.  If you also had other listeners listening on different queues, they would still be free to function since they would be independent threads.

Comment: Correct, the app listens to one queue only. The way I am (re) designing this now is to ensure that any message is retried by a) setting sessiontransacted=true in spring.xml. This causes an automatic retry by JMS. I tested this and confirmed that it happens up to BOTHRESH times after which the message is moved to the BAKOUT queue by the IBM MQ Queue Manager b) Any failure means that either the message itself is a poison message OR the consumer (the app part which writes to the DB) failed. In which case, subsequent messages would then fail as well and be moved to the BAKOUT queue.

Comment: @richc JoshMc- I am creating a new SO question for some duplicate messages that I am seeing with the rollback logic I now have in place. Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: @JoshMc I am creating a new SO question for some duplicate messages that I am seeing with the rollback logic I now have in place. Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: I added an answer.  I updated your question to include the details of `BOTHRESH(1)` being set.  I removed my comments above which I have addressed in my answer.  Please let me know if there is any further details that you would like me to add to my answer.  If you like please accept (and even upvote).  I'll be on the lookout for your next question.

Answer (score 3):

To preserve message ordering, one approach might be to stop the message listener temporarily as part of your rollback strategy. Looking at the [Spring Boot doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html) for `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` there is a `stop(Runnable callback)` method. I've experimented with using this in a rollback as follows.

To ensure my Listener is single threaded, on my `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` I set `containerFactory.setConcurrency("1")`.

In my Listener, I set an `id`

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "DEV.QUEUE.2", containerFactory = "listenerTwoFactory", concurrency="1", id="listenerTwo")
```

And retrieve the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` instance.

```java
JmsListenerEndpointRegistry reg = context.getBean(JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.class);
DefaultMessageListenerContainer mlc = (DefaultMessageListenerContainer) reg.getListenerContainer("listenerTwo");
```

For testing, I check JMSXDeliveryCount and throw an exception to rollback.

```java
retryCount = Integer.parseInt(msg.getStringProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount"));
if (retryCount < 5) {
    throw new Exception("Rollback test "+retryCount);
}
```

In the Listener's catch processing, I call `stop(Runnable callback)` on the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` instance and pass in a new class `ContainerTimedRestart` as defined below.

```java
//catch processing here and decide to rollback
mlc.stop(new ContainerTimedRestart(mlc,delay));
System.out.println("#### "+getClass().getName()+" Unable to process message.");
throw new Exception();
```

`ContainerTimedRestart` extends `Runnable` and `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` is responsible for invoking the `run()` method when the stop call completes.

```java
public class ContainerTimedRestart implements Runnable {

  //Container instance to restart.
  private DefaultMessageListenerContainer theMlc;

  //Default delay before restart in mills.
  private long theDelay = 5000L;

  //Basic constructor for testing.
  public ContainerTimedRestart(DefaultMessageListenerContainer mlc, long delay) {
    theMlc = mlc;
    theDelay = delay;
  }

  public void run(){
    //Validate container instance.

    try {
      System.out.println("#### "+getClass().getName()+"Waiting for "+theDelay+" millis.");
      Thread.sleep(theDelay);
      System.out.println("#### "+getClass().getName()+"Restarting container.");
      theMlc.start();
      System.out.println("#### "+getClass().getName()+"Container started!");
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
      ie.printStackTrace();

      //Further checks and ensure container is in correct state.
      //Report errors.
    }
  }
```

I loaded my queue with three messages with payloads "a", "b", and "c" respectively and started the listener.

Checking `DEV.QUEUE.2` on my queue manager I see `IPPROCS(1)` confirming only one application handle has the queue open. The messages are processed in order after each is rolled five times and with a 5 second delay between rollback attempts.

Answer (score 2):

IBM MQ classes for JMS has poison message handling built in.  This handling is based on the `QLOCAL` setting `BOTHRESH`, this stands for Backout Threshold.  Each IBM MQ message has a "header" called the MQMD (MQ Message Descriptor).  One of the fields in the MQMD is `BackoutCount`.  The default value of BackoutCount on a new message is `0`.  Each time a message rolled back to the queue this count is incremented by 1.  A rollback can be either from a specific call to `rollback()`, or due to the application being disconnected from MQ before commit() is called (due to a network issue for example or the application crashing).

Poison message handling is disabled if you set `BOTHRESH(0)`.

If `BOTHRESH` is >= `1`, then poison message handling is enabled and when IBM MQ classes for JMS reads a message from a queue it will check if the BackoutCount is >= to the BOTHRESH.  If the message is eligible for poison message handling then it will be moved to the queue specified in the `BOQNAME` attribute, if this attribute is empty or the application does not have access to PUT to this queue for some reason, it will instead attempt to put the message to the queue specified in the queue managers `DEADQ` attribute, if it can't put to either of these locations it will be rolled back to the queue.

---

You can find more detailed information on IBM MQ classes for JMS poison message handling in the IBM MQ v9.1 Knowledge Center page [Developing applications>Developing JMS and Java applications>Using IBM MQ classes for JMS>Writing IBM MQ classes for JMS applications>Handling poison messages in IBM MQ classes for JMS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032280_.htm)

Answer (score 2):

In Spring JMS you can define your own container. One container is created for one Jms Destination. We should run a single-threaded JMS listener to maintain the message ordering, to make this work set the concurrency to 1.

We can design our container to return null once it encounters errors, post-failure all receive calls should return null so that no messages are polled from the destination till the destination is active once again.  We can maintain an active state using a timestamp, that could be simple milliseconds. A sample JMS config should be sufficient to add backoff. You can add small sleep instead of continuously returning null from  `receiveMessage` method, for example, sleep for 10 seconds before making the next call, this will save some CPU resources.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JmsConfig {

  @Bean
  public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
      DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory() {
      @Override
      protected DefaultMessageListenerContainer createContainerInstance() {
        return new DefaultMessageListenerContainer() {
          private long deactivatedTill = 0;

          @Override
          protected Message receiveMessage(MessageConsumer consumer) throws JMSException {
            if (deactivatedTill < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
              return receiveFromConsumer(consumer, getReceiveTimeout());
            }
            logger.info("Disabled due to failure :(");
            return null;
          }

          @Override
          protected void doInvokeListener(MessageListener listener, Message message)
              throws JMSException {
            try {
              super.doInvokeListener(listener, message);
            } catch (Exception e) {
              handleException(message);
              throw e;
            }
          }

          private long getDelay(int retryCount) {
            if (retryCount <= 1) {
              return 20;
            }
            return (long) (20 * Math.pow(2, retryCount));
          }

          private void handleException(Message msg) throws JMSException {
            if (msg.propertyExists("JMSXDeliveryCount")) {
              int retryCount = msg.getIntProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount");
              deactivatedTill = System.currentTimeMillis() + getDelay(retryCount);
            }
          }

          @Override
          protected void doInvokeListener(SessionAwareMessageListener listener, Session session,
              Message message)
              throws JMSException {
            try {
              super.doInvokeListener(listener, session, message);
            } catch (Exception e) {
              handleException(message);
              throw e;
            }
          }
        };
      }
    };
    // This provides all boot's default to this factory, including the message converter
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    // You could still override some of Boot's default if necessary.
    return factory;
  }
}
```