# JMS Configuring backoff/retry without blocking onMessage()

Tags: spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

javax.JMS version 2.0.1

Provider : ibm.mq v9.0

Framework : Java Spring boot

From what I know, onMessage() is asynchronous. I am successfully retrying the message send. However, the re-sending of messages happens instantaneously after a message failure. Ideally I want the retry to happen in a sliding window style eg. First retry  after 20 seconds, second retry after 40 etc.

How can I achieve this ***without*** a Thread.Sleep() which, I presume, will block the entire Java thread and is not something I want at all ?

Code is something like this

```java
final int TIME_TO_WAIT = 20;

public void onMessage(Message , message)
{
   :
   :
   int t  =   message.getIntProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount");
   if(t > 1)
   {
     // Figure out a way to wait for (TIME_TO_WAIT * t)
   
   }

}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // Do some logging/cleanup etc.
    throw new RunimeException(e);// this causes a message retry
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use exponential backoff in the retry logic, but you would need to use the [Delivery Delay](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q119200_.htm) feature.

Define a custom JmsTemplate that will use delay property from the message, you should add retry count in the message property as well so that you can delay as per your need like 20, 40, 80, 160, etc

```java
public class DelayedJmsTemplate extends JmsTemplate {
    public static String DELAY_PROPERTY_NAME = "deliveryDelay";
        
    @Override
    protected void doSend(MessageProducer producer, Message message) throws JMSException {
        long delay = -1;
        if (message.propertyExists(DELAY_PROPERTY_NAME)) {
            delay = message.getLongProperty(DELAY_PROPERTY_NAME);
        }
        if (delay >= 0) {
            producer.setDeliveryDelay(delay);
        }
        if (isExplicitQosEnabled()) {
            producer.send(message, getDeliveryMode(), getPriority(), getTimeToLive());
        } else {
            producer.send(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Define Components, that will have the capability fo re-enqueue of the message, you can define this interface in the base message listener. The handleException method should do all the tasks of enqueue and computing delay etc. You may not always interested in enqueuing, in some cases, you would discard messages as well.

You can see a similar post-processing logic here
https://github.com/sonus21/rqueue/blob/4c9c5c88f02e5cf0ac4b16129fe5b880411d7afc/rqueue-core/src/main/java/com/github/sonus21/rqueue/listener/PostProcessingHandler.java

```java
@Component
@Sl4j
public class MessageListener {
    private final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    
    @Autowired
    public MessageListener(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
        this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    }
        
    @JmsListener(destination = "myDestination")
    public void onMessage(Message message) throws JMSException {
        try {
            // do something
        } catch (Exception e) {
            handleException("myDestination", message, e);
        }
    }
    
    // Decide whether the message should be ignored due to many retries etc
    private boolean shouldBeIgnored(String destination, Message message) {
        return false;
    }
    
    // add logic to compute delay
    private long getDelay(String destination, Message message, int deliveryCount) {
        return 100L;
    }
    
    private void handleException(String destination, Message message, Exception e) throws JMSException {
        if (shouldBeIgnored(destination, message)) {
            log.info("destination: {}, message: {} is ignored ", destination, message, e);
            return;
        }
        if (message.propertyExists("JMSXDeliveryCount")) {
            int t = message.getIntProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount");
            long delay = getDelay(destination, message, t + 1);

            message.setLongProperty(DELAY_PROPERTY_NAME, delay);
            message.setIntProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount", t + 1);
            jmsTemplate.send(destination, session -> message);
        } else {
            // no delivery count, is this the first message or should be ignored?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In another SO post the OP has stated that message order matters, so delayed delivery would not work for that use case due to FIFO processing.

Comment: @user1554876 it seems you want to rollback and temporarily pause the listener and then retry. Maybe a Spring expert can comment on the feasibility of that pattern. However, if the problem is with the message itself you'll need a blackout strategy. Typically, this is achieved with `JMSXDeliveryCount`

Comment: @JoshMc I'm not sure about OP's other question, based on this question this should be sufficient to handle the exponential backoff or any backoff. Of course, it will be out of order due to re-enqueue process.

Comment: @user1554876 did you find a solution? I did some experimenting with calling stop on the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`. I used `stop(Runnable callback)` to ensure stop was complete and to control the restart outside of the listener. It was just an experiment and it would be good to get a Spring Boot expert view on such an approach. It might be worth a new SO question.

Comment: @richc - I am creating a new SO question because more than the redelivery, I am more concerned with sporadic duplicate message processing by JMS.

Comment: @user1554876 I updated your other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63292922/ibm-mq-provider-for-jms-how-to-automatically-roll-back-messages/63419804#63419804) to show how `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` might be used.