# timed reading jms template ibm mq

Tags: java, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have the necessity to implement a timed reading of an ibm mq.

I have a client application that read from a queue and in some cases I want avoid the rollback of the transaction, writing the message on a new queue instead of dead letter queue. Then I want reprocess the message after 5 minutes and repeat the process in case of error.

Now I read with a Jms Listener

```
 @JmsListener(destination = "${QueueName}")
 public void readMessages(TextMessage msg) { ...
```

but if the message is not consumed, I would like rewrite it on the queue and wait 5 minutes before read again.
What is the best way to implement a timed reading in this case?

Thank you everyone in advance!

UPDATE

With IBM MQ version 8+ there is the feature Delivery Delay that solve my problem. Cheers!

Comment: Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63292922/ibm-mq-provider-for-jms-how-to-automatically-roll-back-messages/63419804#63419804)

Comment: You should post a self answer with a little more detail for the next lesson looking for a solution.